# JPA EntityManager - when the transaction starts?

Tags: jpa, transactions, ejb, java-ee-7

I am confused about the life cycle of the transactions, the entitymanagers and the persistence context in the EJB container.

I use the entitymanager this way:

```
 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "..")
 private EntityManager em;
```

in every stateless ejb.

My question is as simple as:

1. When the transaction starts ?
2. How the transaction is propagated ? ie when stateless ejbs call each others, does they keep using the same transaction ?
3. When the transaction is committed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For container-managed transactions:

1. The transaction (TX) starts when the first transactional method is invoked. Per default, all EJB methods are transactional ( equivalent to `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED`, which is the default setting).
2. The default TX propagation keeps the same TX over all local EJB calls. This is equivalent to an explicit `TrasactionAttributeType.REQUIRED` on all invoked methods
3. The transaction is committed when the first method in the invocation chain (the one the TX has been created for) returns.

You can have a fine-grained control over the TX propagation by annotating your EJB methods with different [TransactionAttributeTypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html).

Comment: about 3- if I have 3 ejbs: A, B and C. both B and C have the annotation @PersistenceContext and A does not have any entity manager.
So if A calls B to create an entity, then A calls C to create another entity, then we have two different transactions ?

Comment: PersistenceContext is independent of transactions.  The injected PersistenceContext can take part in the transaction, but does not start one.

Comment: if PersistenceContext can not start a transaction, what will start it ?

Comment: I think I see now. You said "all EJB methods are transactional", so the ejb method in A is the one who started the transaction ?

Comment: Exactly, independent of the invocation order, the default case would use a single TX that is propagated over all methods. In your case - from A to B and from A to C. The entity managers of the beans B and C will be enlisted in this TX. It will commit once the method in A returns. The TX is started by the container by default.